# How to connect to several WebSockets providing the same data for redundancy on Javascript so that if some fail, others will ensure things still work?

Tags: javascript, websocket

The intention is to have several websockets for redundancy of the same data, so that if one fails, the others will still do the job. In particular, a setup where any one websocket is enough to keep the system working, even if all others fail to connect or return errors.

This is the curent setup, but I know it's wrong:

```
        let queue = []        
        ws = new WebSocket(`wss://firstsource.com/ws/`);
        ws2 = new WebSocket(`wss://secondsource.com/ws/`);
        ws3 = new WebSocket(`wss://thirdsource.com/ws/`);
        ws4 = new WebSocket(`wss://fourthsource.com/ws/`);
        ws.onopen = sendIntro;
        ws2.onopen = sendIntro;
        ws3.onopen = sendIntro;
        ws4.onopen = sendIntro;
        ws.onmessage = insertQueue;
        ws2.onmessage = insertQueue;
        ws3.onmessage = insertQueue;
        ws4.onmessage = insertQueue;
    
        function sendIntro() {
          ws.send('{"config":"2.0"}')
          ws2.send('{"config":"2.0"}')
          ws3.send('{"config":"2.0"}')
          ws4.send('{"config":"2.0"}')
          ws5.send('{"config":"2.0"}')
        }
    
        function insertQueue(msg) {
            //let's just assume all we want is add the data to a queue
            queue.push(msg); 
        }
```

What's the right way?
Assume the format of the data is identical for all sources.

I considered creating an `onError` function and use that to connect to the second websocket, and then another onError2 to connect to the third websocket, and so on, but it takes a long time to trigger onError when there is no response, so the complete process of testing a few sources if done in series like that would take far too long.

Comment: Queue up messages, send them, if you get an error or disconnect, reconnect and resend. I think socket.io does something like this.

Comment: The problem with waiting for an error to attempt another connection is that it takes a very long time to timeout. The aim is to connect as soon as possible to one of the working sources.

Comment: @Norbert Then just do your own timeout?

Comment: What are the failure modes that you want to design this for? I'd guess that most errors will be due to connection losses, and there's nothing you can do about those.

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution.

I figured all I needed was to ensure that at least one of them connect, not to ensure that if one of them disconnects the others will be ready to take over.

For this reduced problem, this worked:

```
//defined higher up
let sucessfulFirstSocketConnection = false

function sendIntro1() {
  if(!sucessfulFirstSocketConnection){
    sucessfulFirstSocketConnection = true

    ws.send(sendString)
    ws.onmessage = insertQueue;

    ws2.close();
    ws3.close();
    ws4.close();
    ws5.close();
  }
}
function sendIntro2() {
  if(!sucessfulFirstSocketConnection){
    sucessfulFirstSocketConnection = true

    ws2.send(sendString)
    ws2.onmessage = insertQueue;

    ws.close()
    ws3.close();
    ws4.close();
    ws5.close();
  }
}
```

and so on.

I basically let them compete among themselves, and the first one that connects closes the other connections and stops all others from getting in the way. This is achieved very quickly even if only the last WebSocket is the one that is able to connect and all others don't establish a connection.